# UILabel auto shrink to fit height

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Why does auto shrink not auto shrink my label when its font size is clearly to big to fit its content? It works well for shrinking the width, but not height. I am wondering how to fit a label to its edges. When the font size exceeds its maximum height it should of course auto shrink. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]